# Copy binary data from Azure SQL to Azure Blobs using Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use Azure Data Factory to move the contents of an Azure SQL table that holds photo (JPEG) data into JPEG files held in Azure blob storage. There does not seem to be a way to create Binary files in Blob storage using ADF without the binary file being a specific format like AVRO or Parquet. I need to create 'raw' binary blobs.

I've been able to create Parquet files for each row in the SQL table, where the Parquet file contains columns for the Id, ImageType and Data (the varbinary that came from the SQL row). I cannot work out how to get the Data column directly into a binary file called "{id}.jpeg".

So far I have a Lookup activity that queries the SQL Photos table to get the Ids of the rows I want, which feeds a ForEach that executes a pipeline for every id. That pipeline uses the Id to query the Id, ImageType and Data from SQL and writes a Parquet file containing those 3 columns into a blob dataset.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same challenge. Did you manage to get it resolved somehow?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I did stick with Parquet files, but ended up giving up on ADF and just writing a scheduled job in our application to do the transferring.